# Jsf2 Richfaces 4 Fileupload, Display error from Business Logic

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces

I implemented a file upload using jsf2 and richfaces 4. It works quite good with one little mistake.

When i upload my file it can occour that i receive an exception from my business logic. (e.g. file already processed)

How can i manage it to display this exception? I tried to register me for the upload complete and render the form, but with no success.

My Fileupload bean (i tried to set the catched exception over the faces ontext without luck :-/ ) :

```
public void uploadSvg(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getUploadedFile();
    File file = writeFileToDisk(uploadedFile);
    try {
        Utils.getSpringBean(FigureService.class).importFigure(
            file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                file.getName() + " -> " + e.getMessage(), null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        log.error(e,e);
        // TODO display messages
    }
}
```

My page (i am using it for two different fileuploads. hope that doesn't mind) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<body>
    <h:form id="files" >
        <h:messages errorStyle="color:red" warnStyle="color: yellow" />

        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:column>
                <c:if test="#{fileType eq 'svg'}">
                    <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUpload.uploadSvg}"
                        maxFilesQuantity="5" id="uploadsvg" immediateUpload="false"
                        acceptedTypes="svg" allowFlash="false"
                        uploadData="#{fileUpload.uploadedFiles }" autoclear="false">
                        <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="files"/>
                    </rich:fileUpload>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="#{fileType eq 'fm'}">
                    <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUpload.uploadFm}"
                        maxFilesQuantity="5" id="uploadfm" immediateUpload="false" 
                        acceptedTypes="csv" allowFlash="false"
                        uploadData="#{fileUpload.uploadedFiles }" autoclear="false">
                        <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="files"/>
                    </rich:fileUpload>
                </c:if>
            </h:column>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!
greetings,
m

Comment: How can i verify that the uploadcomplete event was triggered? I think this may be the problem.

Comment: And i forgot to metion that my bean is viewscoped. when i try the showcase the refresh works. if i set the showcase session scope to viewscope it dosn't refresh after the complete event too.